# Auto submit form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I need to find a way to auto-submit this form for an individual submit button, with javascript, so that I am able to do something like this:

thispage.php?go=gold  -  will instantly auto-click the submit button for "gold membership" when a user hits this page (if ?go=gold is in the URL).

I don't need any help with the PHP, just the Javascript to submit a specific submit button.

```
if ($_GET['go'] == 'gold') {  
    '** need the code I would put here to auto submit the form for the gold button'
 }
```

(((formatting removed for easier reading)))

```
<form action="payments.php?do=order" method="post" name="MiFormulario">

<input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="1331068360-a3bc1dae4834781f33c7100b66bade8f8d17fafd" />

<input type="hidden" name="do" value="order" />









<legend>Silver Membership</legend>


Cost:<br />

<select name="currency[4]" style="width:125px"><optgroup label="3 Months *">
<option value="0_usd" >US$597.00</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="subscriptionids[4]" value="Order" style="font-weight:normal" />









<legend>Gold Membership</legend>



Cost:<br />

<select name="currency[3]" style="width:125px"><optgroup label="3 Months *">
<option value="0_usd" >US$997.00</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="subscriptionids[3]" value="Order" style="font-weight:normal" />








<legend>Platinum Membership</legend>

Cost:<br />

<select name="currency[2]" style="width:125px"><optgroup label="6 Months *">
<option value="0_usd" >US$1,997.00</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="subscriptionids[2]" value="Order" style="font-weight:normal" />








Cost:<br />

<select name="currency[1]" style="width:125px"><optgroup label="1 Year *">
<option value="0_usd" >US$50.00</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="button" name="subscriptionids[1]" value="Order" style="font-weight:normal" />






</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('formId').submit(); </script>";
```